# Values from API not getting appended to Angular2 Dropdown

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I have the following project flow structure:

**import_product.html**

```html
<div class="row custom_row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">Additional Duty: </div> 
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="product.additional_duty_not_no" (change)="changeAddDutyNotSrNo()" required="required">
                            <option value=" ">-- SELECT --</option>
                            <option *ngFor="let add_duty_not_no_data of product.addl_duty_not_nos" value="{{ addl_duty_not_no_data.notification_no }}">{{ addl_duty_not_no_data.notification_no }}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

**import_product_component.ts**

```
getAddlNotificationDuty() {
    var url = 'api/getBasicNotificationDuty';
    var add_duty_not_no_data : any;
    var ref = this;

    this.jobService.loadRemoteUrl(url)
        .subscribe(
        data => { add_duty_not_no_data = data},
        err => console.error(err),
        () => {
            if (add_duty_not_no_data.length > 0) {
                ref.product.addl_duty_not_nos = add_duty_not_no_data;
            }
        }
    );  
}
```

Now the call is made to the API backend powered by Laravel PHP which successfully returns the desired data in the following array format:

```
[{"notification_no":"012/39"},{"notification_no":"007/97"},{"notification_no":"999/85"}]
```

But unfortunately the dropdown in the frontend is not getting populated with the concerned values. There are no errors in the console.

*console.log* till the .ts component shows objects being returned successfully but it is not getting appended to the dropdown.

Please let me know if you want any more details. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

where do you get

```
basic_duty_not_no_data
```

from?

also I recommend using slightly different flow with handling ajax call

```
add_duty_not_no_data: any

getAddlNotificationDuty() {
    var url = 'api/getBasicNotificationDuty';

    this.jobService.loadRemoteUrl(url)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    this.add_duty_not_no_data = data;
                }                
            },
            err => console.error(err)
        );
}
```

Comment: That is just an object variable I have created to store the iterated array values. Shall I replace it with something else or more meaningful? Thanks for letting me know the different ajax handling approach. Appreciated!!!

Comment: sorry I meant basic_duty_not_no_data. It's not in the scope of the compoenent.

Comment: My bad. I have rectified the error in the question.